# R nested map through columns

Tags: r, loops, apply, tidyverse, purrr

I got a function which was solved here.
This function takes a column filled with annotations and another grouping column and propagates the annotation to rows with missing values.

```
f1 <- function(data, group_col, expand_col){
  data %>%
    dplyr::group_by({{group_col}}) %>%
    dplyr::mutate( 
      {{expand_col}} := dplyr::case_when(
        !is.na({{expand_col}}) ~ 
          {{expand_col}} ,
      any( !is.na({{expand_col}})  ) & is.na({{expand_col}}) ~ 
        paste(unique(unlist(str_split(na.omit({{expand_col}}), " ")) ), 
                         collapse = " "),
      TRUE ~ 
        NA_character_  
    ))  %>%
    dplyr::ungroup()
}
```

Now I would like to do it through many columns grouping columns (`group_col`) and annotations columns (`expand_col`).
So if I have this df:

```
t <- tibble(a = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"), 
            b = c(  1,   1,   1,   1,   2,   2,   2,   2),
            c = c(  1,   1,   2,   2,   3,   3,   4,   4),
            d = c( NA,  NA,  NA, "D", "E",  NA,  NA,  NA),
            e = c("A",  NA, "C",  NA,  NA,  NA, "G", "H")
            )
```

I may apply it like this

```
> t %>%
+   f1(c,e) %>%
+   f1(b,e) %>%
+   f1(c,d) %>%
+   f1(b,d)
# A tibble: 8 x 5
  a         b     c d     e    
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1 a         1     1 D     A    
2 b         1     1 D     A    
3 c         1     2 D     C    
4 d         1     2 D     C    
5 e         2     3 E     G H  
6 f         2     3 E     G H  
7 g         2     4 E     G    
8 h         2     4 E     H
```

So, I have 3 groups of columns, the ids, the grouping columns (2:3), and annotation columns (4:5).
Since I call the function many times, I'd like to know how to use the map function to pass the column indexes to apply the function like in the example above.

I tried something like this

```
3:2 %>% 
  map(
    function(x) 4:5 %>% 
      map(
        function(y) f1(
          t, 
          !!(colnames(t)[x]) , 
          !!(colnames(t)[y])
        ) 
      )
  )
```

But the result is a wrong mess.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need pass `c`, `e` as quoted strings.  Also, is this sequential application of function

Comment: Yes, this is a sequential application of the function. I think it should be quoted because `t %>% f1(3, 5)` doesn't work. But I'd like to pass as the column index, like column 3 and 5 but I think `dplyr` does not accept it.

Comment: Actually, I figure out that it works `t %>% f1( !!(colnames(t)[3]) , !!(colnames(t)[5]) )`. So I jutst need to understand how do it sequentially with map (or maybe apply).

Comment: @akrun I added a try which may be a template to what I want.

Comment: The issue with `map` is it is not sequential, you may have to do a `coalesce` afterwards. i would check `?compose`

Comment: Course, `compose` belongs to `purrr`, I never used. Also, I understood about use `coalesce` but I didn't understand how combine them to get the results I want.

Comment: I think a `for` loop makes it easier. `i1 <- 3:2; i2 <- 4:5; for(i in seq_along(i1)) t <- f1(!! rlang::sym(names(t)[.x]), !! rlang::sym(names(t)[.y])`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201119/discussion-between-aureliano-guedes-and-akrun).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `f1` accepts column names, you need to first convert your indices to symbols:

```
v1 <- rlang::syms( colnames(t)[3:2] )
v2 <- rlang::syms( colnames(t)[4:5] )
```

Now, you can use `tidyr::crossing()` to get all possible pairs of your symbols, and `purrr::reduce2()` to sequentially apply `f1()` with those symbols:

```
V <- tidyr::crossing( v1, v2 )
Res <- purrr::reduce2( V$v1, V$v2, f1, .init=t )

# Validation
Res2 <- t %>% f1(c,e) %>% f1(b,e) %>% f1(c,d) %>% f1(b,d)
identical(Res, Res2)   # TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done easily in a `for` loop

```
i1 <- rep(names(t)[3:2], 2)
i2 <- rep(names(t)[4:5], each = 2)
for(i in seq_along(i1))
t <- f1(t, !! rlang::sym(i1[i]), !! rlang::sym(i2[i]))
t
# A tibble: 8 x 5
#  a         b     c d     e    
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>
#1 a         1     1 D     A    
#2 b         1     1 D     A    
#3 c         1     2 D     C    
#4 d         1     2 D     C    
#5 e         2     3 E     G H  
#6 f         2     3 E     G H  
#7 g         2     4 E     G    
#8 h         2     4 E     H
```

Comment: I don't know why but it not worked. Also, I'd like to avoid the side effect. But anyway I tried this way `for(i in 4:5){ for(j in 3:2){ t <- f1(t, !!(colnames(t)[j]), !!(colnames(t)[i])) } } `

Comment: @AurelianoGuedes. A closing bracket I forgot to add

Comment: `Error in !rlang::sym(names(t)[i]) : invalid argument type 
4.
eval(lhs, parent, parent) 
3.
eval(lhs, parent, parent) 
2.
data %>% dplyr::group_by({
    {
        group_col
    } ... 
1.
f1(!!rlang::sym(names(t)[i]), !!rlang::sym(names(t)[i])) 
`

Comment: It is updated `> packageVersion('rlang'); packageVersion('dplyr');
[1] ‘0.4.0’
[1] ‘0.8.3’
`

Comment: @AurelianoGuedes. Sorry, forgot about the 'i1' and 'i2'

Comment: @akrun: I don't think this is correct, because it will only do `f1(c,d)` and `f1(b,e)` and miss the other two combinations (`f1(c,e)` and `f1(b,d)`). If using `for`, it should be a nested loop that considers all combinations of `i1` and `i2`.